# Как найти максимум в каждой строке и изменить цвет этой ячейки?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных

Есть dataframe типа

| index | P | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| B | 2 | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| C | 0 | 2 | 0 | 7 |

Мне надо найти максимум по каждой строке в столбцах x1 x2 и x3 и выделить его цветом.

Мой код:

```
s2 = _df_Velu.style
def highlight_max(s, props=''):
    return np.where(s == np.nanmax(s.values), props, '')
s2.apply(highlight_max, props='color:white;background-color:green;', axis=1)
s2
```

Но это ломает датафрейм и максимум ищет по всей строке, а надо по определенным столбцам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

пример решения вашей задачи есть в документации `pandas` [здесь](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply). Это оттуда:

```
def highlight_max(x, color):
    return np.where(x == np.nanmax(x.to_numpy()), f"color: {color};", None)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['P',"A", "B"])

df.style.apply(highlight_max, color='blue', axis=1, subset=['A','B'])
```

результат работы этого примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [параметром `subset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Finer-Control-with-Slicing).

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
slice_ = idx[:, "x1":"x3"]
df.style.apply(highlight_max, props='color:white;background-color:green;', axis=1, subset=slice_)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]